# Need to create custom ISO for Ubuntu 22.04 that can install OS on thin clients with 8GB flash

Tags: custom-distributions, custom-installer

I need to create a custom Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop ISO that has only required set of packages and has the ability to get installed on systems with 8gb of flash (this is the reason to strip down some of the heavy packages).

Initially, I tried to customise with Cubic, but, that didn't help me much. Then I followed the instructions in the link https://github.com/mvallim/live-custom-ubuntu-from-scratch and added few more customisation on top of it. The resultant ISO boots just fine and I can install OS on a VirtualBox or VMWare virtual machines.

But, for some reason, the ISO fails to boot when used on a real hardware, like Dell Laptops or Supermicro small servers. I did search questions related to this subject in ask-ubuntu, but, they seem to be different. Can someone put some light on this?

Regards,

Muralidhara Kakkunje

Comment: Have you looked into Ubuntu Core? That is what it is made for a kiosk.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try until today. Before replying to you, I tried with generic image and used dd to deploy the ubuntu-core image. My Dell Lattitude 3420 refused to boot. At the same time, if I use the ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso, the laptop never complains of anything and OS gets installed. I am finding it difficult to understand what is missing with custom ISO that is present on the default downloaded ubuntu 22.04 desktop ISO. Any thoughts?

Note: I am going to try to use default desktop ISO and customize the installation using autoinstall. Not sure how much successful will I be :)

Comment: Personally before giving up on Core I would have made a boot USB and tried to install it the traditional way. It might be the method you used that failed?

Comment: `with 8GB flash` does that imply attempting to start the installation from a "pen-drive"? You might need some special tool to get that working e.g. Startup-disk-creator, Rufus, ... I haven't tried similar things so cannot tell more. Actually, guessing; the "thin client" might have special requirements to start the boot.